# What's the difference between clear() and stop() in PooledConnectionFactory in ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, connection-pooling

I'd like to know the difference between  clear() and stop() in the PooledConnectionFactory class.  Is it safe to stop the connections directly without clearing them first?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`clear()`](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/jms/pool/PooledConnectionFactory.html#clear--), it says:

> Clears all connections from the pool. Each connection that is currently in the pool is closed and removed from the pool. A new connection will be created on the next call to [`createConnection()`](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/jms/pool/PooledConnectionFactory.html#createConnection--). Care should be taken when using this method as Connections that are in use be client's will be closed.

As the warning at the end says, calling `clear()` is not safe if the connections are in use.

`stop()` will stop the pool, preventing new connections from being created. Stopping the pool will clear it too.